# Identifying variables contributing to near multicollinearty in linear regression using VIF's and multiple R squared's

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, svd, variance-inflation-factor

**When trying to detect collinear columns in $X$ a high proportion of cases give a $R_k^2$ close to 1 for independent columns (see figure).**

When near multicollinearity arise in a $n\times m$ data matrix $X$,
$$X = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} X_1 & \cdots & X_k & \cdots & X_m \end{array}\right]$$ 
to be used in the linear regression, $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$, I'm trying to give information to the user on which columns of $X$ are contributing to the trouble.

Say I have identified a near collinear $X$, then my strategy is to normalize $X$ by demeaning the columns and scaling them to have standard deviation $1/\sqrt{n}$. Denoting the normalized matrix by $\tilde{X}$, normalization ensures that $\tilde{X}^\prime \tilde{X}$ is an estimator of the $m\times m$ correlation matrix.

According to [section 3.3 in this note from ECB](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1235.pdf?6c77e690812d8bc351facc9e6475fdbf), which is citing [Marquardt (1970)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.1970.10488699), the variance inflation factors (VIF's) can be computed by the SVD of $\tilde{X}$, like so,

$$VIF_k = \sum_{j=1}^m \left(\frac{v_{k,j}}{s_j}\right)^2$$

where the SVD of $\tilde{X} = USV^\prime$, with $S=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} s_{1} &  & 0\\  & \ddots\\ 0 &  & s_{m} \end{array}\right)$ and $V=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
v_{1,1} & \cdots & v_{1,m}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
v_{m,1} & \cdots & v_{m,m}
\end{array}\right)$.

The multiple $R^2_k$'s, that is the $R^2$ from regressing $X_k$ on all other columns of $X$ (that is $\{X_{i\neq k}\}$), including an intercept, are given by $$R^2_k=1-\frac{1}{VIF_k}.$$

In Python code:

```
import numpy as np

def normalize(x):
    x_dm = (x - x.mean(axis=0))
    return x_dm / np.sqrt((x_dm**2).sum(axis=0))


def vif(right_singular_v, singular_values):
    return ((right_singular_v/singular_values)**2).sum(axis=1)


def multiple_r_squared(vif):
    return 1 - 1/vif

n = 100
np.random.seed(11)
x1 = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 1))
x2 = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 1))
x3 = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 1))
x4 = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 1))
x5 = 0.5*x3 + 0.5*x4   # x5 is perfectly linear combination of x3 and x4
x = np.concatenate([x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], axis=1)

u, s, v_t = np.linalg.svd(normalize(x), full_matrices=False)
vifs = vif(right_singular_v=v_t.T, singular_values=s)
print(multiple_r_squared(vifs))
>> [ 0.07771458  0.9822463   1.          1.          1.        ]
```

In the above code example `x2` is independent of the other `x`'s but the multiple $R^2$ value is calculated at 0.98 which would indicate a that `x2` highly correlates with the remaining four variables.

When running a simulation where I repeat the above 10,000 times I get the following distribution of multiple $R^2$'s.

[image]

Inspecting the histogram of `x2` we see that in approximately 50% of the cases  we would reach the false conclusion that `x2` is contributing to multicollinearity in `x`. As the sample size `n` grows this problem diminishes.

Hoping that my logic and code is correct... 
**Why is the multiple $R^2$ value of `x2` calculated close to 1 in so many cases? Are there, for example, some small sample considerations to take into account, i.e. some asymptotic behavior of the $R_k^2$ estimator that hasn't kicked in yet with only n=100?**

Comment: "Thoughts about [these] phenomena" is so vague that it's hard to know what would constitute an answer.  Please ask a specific question.

Comment: @whuber: Just edited the final question.